# What is a matrix with unit normal entries?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

[image]

1. What are unit normal entries?
2. Is a matrix with unit normal entries the same as a "normal matrix"?

Comment: Please [edit] to tell us the context in which you found this matrix.

Answer (score 0):

1. The entries in the matrix are random numbers chosen independently from a normal distribution with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution

The standard normal distribution, represented by the letter Z, is the normal distribution having a mean of 0 and a standard deviation of 1.

2. "Normal matrix" means something else, not relevant for this problem.
   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_matrix

Answer (score 0):

You left off a word from the context. It says "random matrix with unit normal entries". The word "random" suggests that "normal" refers to the gaussian distribution. Googling "random unit normal" got me "In probability theory, the normal distribution is a very common continuous probability ... A random variable with a Gaussian distribution is said to be normally .... (i.e. the variance is equal to one), and therefore also unit standard deviation." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution and "unit normal distribution" got "A normal distribution such that the mean μ = 0 and standard deviation σ = 1" http://glossary.ametsoc.org/wiki/Unit_normal_distribution